# Remove corner shadow/offset in grouped UITableView

Tags: ipad, uitableview

When a UITableView of type UITableViewStyleGrouped has a background view that is a non-default color or pattern image on the iPad, the rounded corners have an ugly extra line, sort of like a bevel effect or drop shadow:

[image: ugly table view corners]

Does anyone know of any way to get rid of the extra line at the bottom of the table?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The default separator style for iPad is `UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLineEtched`. This is different from the iPhone's default of `UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine`.

If you would like to remove the bevel, set the `separatorStyle` of the view to `UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine`.

Note that the default separator style in iOS 5 for both devices is SingleLineEtched.

Comment: thank you for this answer, worked for me with a white background color

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem when using [UIColor scrollViewTexturedBackgroundColor]. I managed to remove the "bevel effect" / "drop shadow" by using the code below:

self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;

Answer (score 1):

I replaced the tableView's backgroundView with a new view.

I then relied on the tableView's backgroundColor property to set the color I wanted:

```
self.tableView.backgroundView = [[[UIView alloc] init] autorelease];
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the Content Inset of the bottom of your table view to something like -20 px.  You may need to play around with the value.

Comment: That doesn't seem to do anything. Have you seen an example of this working?

Comment: Yes, in my app, without it I see the "chin", with it the bevel is gone.  I'm sorry it didn't work for you...  We must be doing something else differently.