# How to fix border in UITableView for the UITableViewStyleGrouped

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitableview

For a `UITableViewStyleGrouped` `UITableView` a small extra line is drawn below the tableview

How do I fix this?

I have tried my best. No luck so far.

Thank's in advance.

My Code

```
-(void)myTableView
{
//  if(mytableView != nil)
//  [mytableView release];

    if (mytableView == nil) {

        mytableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:myFrame style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];

    }
    mytableView.delegate=self;
    mytableView.dataSource=self;
    mytableView.backgroundView=nil;
    mytableView.scrollEnabled = FALSE;
    [self.view addSubview:mytableView];
    [self myPortraitMode];
}
```

Background of the table is fixed is an image.

Comment: You will have to explain your self clearly? What exactly is your problem?

Comment: @user891268, That is the default style of grouped table views. Why do you want to change that?

Comment: It looks bad if you do not set a background view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a background view:

```
UIView *backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] init];
backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yourColor];
tableview.backgroundView = backgroundView;
[backgroundView release];
```

You don't need to set the properties every time.

```
-(void)myTableView
{
    if (mytableView == nil) {
        mytableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:myFrame style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
        mytableView.delegate=self;
        mytableView.dataSource=self;
        mytableView.backgroundView=nil;
        mytableView.scrollEnabled = NO;
        [self.view addSubview:mytableView];
        [self myPortraitMode];
    }
}
```

I don't really see what the problem is though.

Comment: Have you got a bigger picture of the problem and the code of how you are setting up the table view?

Comment: for the backgroundView Its an image. on the the UITableview

Comment: The correct answer for this question is the one by @Code Monkey.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are referring to is the Bevel color of the table view.
The answer is in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6079403/remove-corner-shadow-offset-in-grouped-uitableview).
Basically, you need to set the table `separatorStyle` to `UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone` or to `UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine`.

Comment: This is the correct answer, the selected one is for changing the whole background, not to remove the extra line as requested.